# Method "getElementsByClassName" not recognized

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, powershell

I want to start Windows Explorer and login to a website. After logging in I want to click logout textlink. But I am getting this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass] doesn't contain a
method named 'getElementsByClassName'
At C:\Users\ntando.ntuli\Desktop\test.ps1:29 char:43
+  $Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByClassName <<<< ("underline") | Where-Object {$_.ClassName -eq "underline"}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementsByClassName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Here is the code I am using

```psh
$IE = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application;
$IE.Visible = $true;
$IE.Navigate("http://192.168.2.73:6500/ouaf/loginPage.jsp");

# Wait a few seconds and then launch the executable.
while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;
}

# The following UsernameElement, PasswordElement, and LoginElement need to be
# modified first.  See the notes at the top of the script for more details.

$elementMatchText = "You are logged in as English System"
$IE.Document.getElementById("userId").value = "username"
$IE.Document.getElementByID("password").value="password"
$IE.Document.getElementById("loginButton").Click()

while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000; 
} 

#Logout textlink classname
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("underline") |
        Where-Object {$_.ClassName -eq "underline"}
$Link.Click()
```

Comment: The script below works when looking for tag-names before logging-in $Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') |
        Where-Object { $_.ClassName -eq 'underline' } |
        Select-Object -First 1 . But when logged-in it gives me this error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.". I am not sure if it is because after I logged-in the url changes from http://192.168.2.73:6500/ouaf/loginPage.jsp to http://192.168.2.73:6500/ouaf/cis.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can only call `getElementsByClassName` on the `documentElement` property of the Document:

```
$ie.Document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName("underline")
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias R. Jessen for the answer I have struggling with for almost today.Enjoy!

Comment: I was struggling whole week, 
Thanks alot, 
Tell me why and how it works ?

Comment: @AshishKamble because the `Document` element is the only DOM element that expose/implement that function

Answer (score 0):

I've seen `getElementsByClassName()` fail before, even though it *should* work, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975198.aspx). As a workaround select your elements by tag name (you seem to be looking for `<a>` tags), then filter for the `ClassName` attribute. I'd also restrict the results to the first occurrence in case more than one matching element is found:

```
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') |
        Where-Object { $_.ClassName -eq 'underline' } |
        Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: I used the script you provided I get a different error saying (in getElementsByTagName I have 'span' instead of 'a') : + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Click:String) [], RuntimeException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull . My assumption is because after logging-in the url changes from  http://192.168.2.73:6500/ouaf/loginPage.jsp  to http://192.168.2.73:6500/ouaf/cis.jsp