# "Method Not found" error when calling GetElementsbyClassName

Tags: powershell, automation, internet-explorer-11, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I created a PowerShell automation script and I gave it to my friend when he run it, it said

```
Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLBodyClass] does not contain a method
named 'getElementsByClassName'.
At C:\Users\עמית\Documents\asaf.ps1:22 char:3
+   $a=$docs.body.getElementsByClassName("FadeOut-Scroll")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

why is that happened?

We both have IE11, .net 4.5, Visual studio, but I have that function and he not.

And it looks like here in his computer the IE console have the function:

[image]

but PowerShell does not:

[image]

How to update PowerShell?

Comment: [Perhaps related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34785024/1630171).

Comment: That's a question only Microsoft can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found after alot  of time:

the missing want [microsoft core xml](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19662)