# Trying to use Powershell to automate a login to an IP phone and then reboot it.

Tags: powershell, automation

I am trying to create a Powershell script that will open Internet Explorer to the IP address of an IP phone, input user credintials, log in, and then click on the reboot option.

I am having issues with getting the script to get beyond opening the web portal though.  Here is my Powershell script.

```
<#
Created:  November 8, 2017
Version 1.0
Description:  Launch Internet Explorer to the specified URL, log into the site, and then click the reboot command on the page.
Notes:



#>

#Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

# Edit this to be the URL or IP address of the site to be launched

$Url = "10.0.4.239"

# Edit this to be the UserName

$Username = "admin"

# Edit this to be the corresponding Password

$Password = "admin"

# Invoke Internet Explorer

$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$IE.Visible = $true;
$IE.navigate($url);

# Wait a few secconds for the page to load

while ($IE.Busy -eq $true)

{

  Start-Sleep -Seconds 4;

}

<#

The following UsernameElement, PasswordElement, and LoginElement need to be modified first.

#>

$IE.Document.getElementByClassName("gwt-TextBox").value = $username;
$IE.Document.getElementByClassName("gwt-PasswordTextBox").value = $Password;
$IE.Document.getElementByClassName("gwt-Button").Click();

do
   {
    Sleep 25
   }
   while ($ie.Busy -eq "True")
```

Here is a screen shot of the errors that I receive.

[Powershell error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAnCh.png)

Here is the source code for the input fields and login button.

[WebApp Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1KNs.png)

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: This bit is tangential: you may not want to have the username and password in the script.  Have them be parameters and use `Get-Credential` would be a simple solution to improve the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785024/method-getelementsbyclassname-not-recognized

Comment: Thanks for the info Bryce, I will try that next.  Thank you for the link will, I will make sure to avoid that in the future.  Thanks again, everybody for the help.

Comment: There is not a `getElelmentByClassName` method on the `Document`. Your choices are `getElementById`, `getElementsByName`, or `getElementsByTagName`.